# How do I insert site information data into another table?

Tags: database

I have developed website using Drupal. I have created an application without using Drupal, using another framework. In my application I also stored site logo,site name etc. I want to update  my site information table when updating 
Drupal site information from admin/settings/site-information.

The fields are the following ones:

- id: int(12), primary key
- site_title: varchar(60)
- site_logo: varchar(200)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but I guess one simple and 'drupalish' way to do this:

[Define multiple databases in your drupal instance](http://drupal.org/node/18429)

Set your 2 databases to be available to drupal.

Then, it is just a matter of deciding when you want to fetch  and update the data.

You could use hook_install (or hook_enable) and add a query in there that would load your data in drupal database when enabling the module. Or, you could create a callback that would update the data when you visit a certain url, all of this is up to you.

Hope this helps, good-luck.

Comment: Thanks, glad this helped you. Not that it changes much, but you *are* allowed to upvote the accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to add a submit function to the form, see http://drupal.org/node/222158 (for D6 but should be the same for D7).

In your new submit function you can do whatever you want...

You can query other database following this doc http://drupal.org/node/18429

```
  $other_database = array(
      'database' => 'databasename',
      'username' => 'username', // assuming this is necessary
      'password' => 'password', // assuming this is necessary
      'host' => 'localhost', // assumes localhost
      'driver' => 'mysql', // replace with your database driver
  );
  // replace 'YourDatabaseKey' with something that's unique to your module
  Database::addConnectionInfo('YourDatabaseKey', 'default', $other_database);
  db_set_active('YourDatabaseKey');

  // execute queries here

  db_set_active(); // without the paramater means set back to the default for the site
  drupal_set_message(t('The queries have been made.'));
```